# Derivative of composition with confusing moment

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^1$ and $\mathbf{p}:\mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and they are differentiable. Define $f(\mathbf{p}(t))$ and consider that $f'(\mathbf{p}(t))$ exists? I know that it's a linear transformation but what it's domain and range?

Our function is the following $f'\circ \mathbf{p}(t)$. It domain is $\mathbb{R}^1$ and it's range is also $\mathbb{R}^1$. So $f'\circ \mathbf{p}(t) \in L(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Am I right?

I am sorry but this topic is repeated and I can't understand the previous one.

Comment: Please include the differentiabiliy assumptions on $f$ and $p.$

Comment: @zhw., I edited!

Comment: @zhw., Is my reasoning right or not?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Alex, I guess that he is wrong! Because for any fixed $t\in \mathbb{R}^1$ we have $\mathbf{p}(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence $f'(\mathbf{p}(t))$ is a linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^1$

Comment: @RFZ Hmm, I thought of that before posting my answer.  But then I thought of $f(p(t))'$ instead of $f'(p(t))$, for which his reasoning would be correct, since $f\circ p$ is a $\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ function.  So actually $f'(p(t))$ is a linear transformation from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^n$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative $f'$ associates to each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the derivative of $f$ at $x$, which is a linear map $f'(x):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. You can thus view the derivative as a map $f':\mathbb{R}^n \to L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$. As such the composition $f' \circ p:\mathbb{R} \to L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, and $f'(p(t)) \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is the derivative of $f'$ at $p(t)$. Note that in this setting it might be preferable to write $D_x f$, $T_x f$, $(df)_x$ or something similar instead of $f'(x)$.